# owed back pay from head office

Tags: salary

We are a group of 7 ladies who perform cooking demos at a large warehouse supermarket. There was a change of management beginning of January and that's when the "glitches" started happening. The new manager said she had to get up to speed on the computer and in fact had to be sent one from the corporate office which is in CA...we are in PA.  We work with a computer program called JET where we log in our demos and hours.  We have been asked to work since January 22nd quite a few days that were not in the computer and, thus, we have not been paid since then. A few of the ladies have logged in up to 10 days.  We are constantly being told that it's being worked on and that the corporate office is taking care of it.  Every pay day....no back pay.  And it continues to happen if we are asked to work on a day that doesn't appear in the program.  What to do?

Comment: Given that the employer is in California, the California Department of Industrial Relations may be able to help you. https://www.dir.ca.gov/dlse/dlseWagesAndHours.html and https://www.dir.ca.gov/dlse/HowToFileWageClaim.htm

Comment: @Kathy IANAL but I do think local employment will have jurisdiction.  I worked for two out of state startups that went under and they shorted me some pay and the employment commission in my state got me paid.

Comment: @Frisbee Hence the "may". Hopefully my comment will inspire someone in PA to post a link to that state's employment commission, too. :)

Answer (score 6):

I would start with your local employment commission.  They have teeth and they are free.

Answer (score 2):

Have your manager confirm in writing every day worked to this point and every future day not on the regular schedule until all backpay is received.To make it easy for her, email along the lines of "Please confirm that I have worked the following dates and hours: Feb 1-6 hrs, Feb 11-8hrs...".  If a manager is resistant to this that would throw a big red flag for me. Once it is documented that this these days were worked but not paid, you are ensured they will be paid when the billing problem is solved.

With respect to pushing this along so the problem does get solved, see Jimm101's excellent answer.

Answer (score 1):

Bureaucracies. Someday science will find a cure.

Until then--people will suggest many solutions, but as any good admin can tell you, they best way to get someone to move this stuff through is to "sit on them" or "walk it through".

"Sit on them" means to keep the person on the phone until it's entered, or get an exact time to call back when it will be entered, and then call exactly at that time. You're now advertising that solving the problem will be simpler than ignoring it and hoping it magically resolves itself.

"Walk it through" means getting person A to do the person A thing while on the phone (or in person), and then asking the next person in the process, and the phone number there, and calling that person and asking when it will be time for the next step, etc. Basically, you sit on person A, then person B, then ... check comes out on payday. Or, more likely, the check isn't correct, and someone finally understands that things are broken. Usually the next check will have it.

In either case the responsibility is either (a) sitting with someone who doesn't care), or (b) has diffused into some adminsphere to never return. Either way, you become the annoying task they are ignoring, and by getting in their face a bit, the task gets done.

The advantages of this are: no lost work time, you get the money, and you really don't make it adversarial. Just smile when sitting on people and nod your head when they tell you how the rest of the process won't work, but that their part is fine.

Answer (score 0):

First sorry that you're in this situation.

You should get a clear **deadline** of when you will receive your back pay and verify the amount. Remember to document days you worked outside of the JET program. **Escalate** the problem to higher management, payroll, and/or human resources. Depending on your financial situation, refuse to work days not scheduled within the JET program.

Good luck.